how to add a double click event for 2 nested listbox WPF C#
<Window x:Class="SecutiryQuizApp.Views.Windows.CreateOrEditInspection"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SecutiryQuizApp.Views.Windows"
        xmlns:contols="clr-namespace:SecutiryQuizApp.UserControls"
        xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SecutiryQuizApp.Converters"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Обход" Height="600" Width="600" Icon="/Resources/inspections.ico">
    <Window.Resources>
        <converter:TypeAnswerConverter x:Key="TypeAnswerConverter"/>
        <converter:BooleanInverterConverter x:Key="BooleanInverterConverter"/>
        <converter:Base64ToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="Base64ToBitmapImageConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="519*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="564*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding QuizCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuiz, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Выберите опрос..." FontFamily="Bahnschrift" FontSize="16" Background="White" IsEnabled="{Binding VisibilityDonut, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
                <ListBox x:Name="QuestionsList" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionsCollection}" Margin="0,10,0,10" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="{Binding VisibilityDonut, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}" >
                    <ListBox.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ListBox.Template>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 -2 0 0"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="7">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Name="name" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10 5 0 0" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Bahnschrift"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Opacity="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Text="{Binding idTypeAnswer, Converter={StaticResource TypeAnswerConverter}}"  MaxHeight="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Name="description" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10 7 0 0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Bahnschrift"/>
                                                    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ImagesList" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagePathsCollection}" MaxHeight="120" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" CornerRadius="15">
                                                                    <Grid>
                                                                        <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Base64ToBitmapImageConverter}}" Width="35" Height="35"/>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    </ListBox>
                                                    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" x:Name="ListAnswers"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="LightYellow">
                                                        <ListBox.Template>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                                                                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False">
                                                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                                                </ScrollViewer>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </ListBox.Template>
                                                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 -2 0 0"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="7">
                                                                                <Grid>
                                                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                        <TextBlock Text="Ответ: " FontSize="20" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Answer}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Background="Red" Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,5,0" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveMarkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                                                                        <Button.Template>
                                                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                                                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="20">
                                                                                                    <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Width="10" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                                                                        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial.Style>
                                                                                                            <Style TargetType="iconPacks:PackIconMaterial">
                                                                                                                <Setter Property="Kind" Value="close"/>
                                                                                                            </Style>
                                                                                                        </iconPacks:PackIconMaterial.Style>
                                                                                                    </iconPacks:PackIconMaterial>
                                                                                                </Border>
                                                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                                                        </Button.Template>
                                                                                    </Button>
                                                                                </Grid>
                                                                            </Border>
                                                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                                <MultiTrigger>
                                                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                                                                                </MultiTrigger>
                                                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                                                                                </Trigger>
                                                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                                                                                </Trigger>
                                                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </Style>
                                                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                        
                                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDoubleClick">
                                                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenAnswerEditCommand, ElementName=ListAnswers}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                    </ListBox>


                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <MultiTrigger>
                                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="description" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" BeginTime="0:0:0" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="description" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" BeginTime="0:0:0" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#edeaf4"/>
                                            </MultiTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#eff3fb"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFECECEC"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditOrAddQuestionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=QuestionsList}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ListBox>

                <Button Grid.Row="4" Content="Сохранить изменения" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding SaveQuizCommand}" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="#FF2196F3" BorderBrush="#FF2196F3" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" FontSize="16" IsEnabled="{Binding VisibilityDonut, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}"/>

            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="119*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="37*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" FontSize="22" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5"><Run Language="ru-ru" Text="Обход"/></TextBlock>
            <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="Удалить обход" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Command="{Binding RemoveQuizCommand}" Background="#FFFF4C30" BorderBrush="#FF2196F3" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" FontSize="16" IsEnabled="{Binding VisibilityDonut, Converter={StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
        </Grid>
        <contols:DonutSpinner  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityDonut, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MaxWidth="80"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
using SecutiryQuizApp.Models;
using SecutiryQuizApp.ViewModels;
using System.Windows;

namespace SecutiryQuizApp.Views.Windows
{
    public partial class CreateOrEditInspection : Window
    {
        public CreateOrEditInspection(InspectionAnswer inspection)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new OpenOrEditInspectionVM(inspection);
        }
    }
}
 public RelayCommand OpenAnswerEditCommand
 {
     get
     {
         return new RelayCommand(parameter =>
         {
             if (parameter is InspectionAnswer question)
             {
                 OpenEditAnswer(question);
             }
         });
     }
 }
 private InspectionAnswer inspection {  get; set; }
 public OpenOrEditInspectionVM(InspectionAnswer _inspection)
 {
     inspection = _inspection;
     Runner();
 }

I'm facing an issue with a PreviewMouseDoubleClick OpenAnswerEditCommand event not working as expected in my WPF application. I have a ListBox named ListAnswers, and I want to trigger the OpenAnswerEditCommand command in my view model when a ListBoxItem within ListAnswers is double-clicked. However, despite setting up the event trigger in XAML, the command does not seem to be executed.

Bind to the DataContext of the second ListBox parent:
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenAnswerEditCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox, AncestorLevel=2}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>

Or the parent window:
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenAnswerEditCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>

You cannot use ElementName here since the nested ListBox is in a different namescope than the outer one.
